# how to get get matching record from jsonArray node js java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

jsonArray

```
[ { serial: '111',
    certificateNumber: 'CCT1',
    calibrationDate: '2018-01-02',
    gaugeDescription: 'newR',
    certificateName: '111.png',
    email: 'chetde@dev.com',
    dueDate: '2018-02-03' 
 },
  { serial: '222',
    certificateNumber: 'CCT2',
    calibrationDate: '2018-02-14',
    gaugeDescription: 'newRR',
    certificateName: '222.png',
    email: 'chetaayade@devcom',
    dueDate: '2018-01-16' 
},
  { serial: '333',
    certificateNumber: 'CCT3',
    calibrationDate: '2018-01-08',
    gaugeDescription: 'Records',
    certificateName: '333.png',
    email: 'chetan@dev.com',
    dueDate: '2018-01-18' } 
]
```

Uploded Docs

```
[ '333.png', '222.png' ]
```

how to filter by uploaded Docs

Comment: Simple 2 for loops can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following (use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

```
var arr = [.....]; // your array
var uploadedDocs = [ '333.png', '222.png' ];

arr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return uploadedDocs.indexOf(item.certificateName) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `filter` and `includes`

```
var uploadedDocs = [ '333.png', '222.png' ];
var output = jsonArray.filter( s => uploadedDocs.includes( s.certificateName ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter(item)` and `indexOf()` functions:

```
var uploadedDocs = [ '333.png', '222.png' ];
var filteredDocs = jsonArray.filter(item => item.indexOf(uploadedDocs) !== -1);
```

Comment: Your answer is almost same as mine. What prompted you to bring this up? I am curious to know the reason.

Comment: ahh missed your answer somehow.

Comment: No issue at all :)